# Python Flask on Heroku repeatedly logs "Permission Denied"

Tags: python, flask, heroku

My Python Flask app is able to `git push` to heroku no problem, but after pushing, when checking the logs with `heroku logs --tail`, it repeatedly logs:

```
2022-08-24T17:07:47.065727+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-24 17:07:47 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21
2022-08-24T17:07:47.100592+00:00 app[web.1]: * Serving Flask app 'app'
2022-08-24T17:07:47.100599+00:00 app[web.1]: * Debug mode: off
2022-08-24T17:07:47.101990+00:00 app[web.1]: Permission denied                       <-- here
2022-08-24T17:07:47.102149+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-24 17:07:47 +0000] [21] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21)
```

Over and over again with different pid.

My project structure:

```
MyApp\
  src\
    static\...
    templates\...
    app.py
  Procfile
  requirements.txt
```

My Procfile is `web: gunicorn --pythonpath src app` and my app.py is:

```py
# ... imports

app = Flask(__name__)

# ... routes

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80, threaded=True)
```

I don't know what permission is being denied, or how it is being denied, or how to fix it. Tried searching around, all the results were for "[Errno ...] Permission Denied", which is different from mine.

Comment: What you bother?

Comment: Are you trying to log to a file or something?

Comment: @Chris That's the problem, I am not doing anything to any files, and I have no idea what is causing the "permission denied"

Answer (score 1):

heroku has set the port itself, so you can't assign flask port=80 here
try this

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 80)), threaded=True)
```

remember to "import os" at the top
hope this help